# Getting 500 internal server error on Foursquare app

Tags: php, api, file-get-contents, foursquare, connection-timeout

I am getting "`500 internal server error`" on my Foursquare app. 
On server Side, There is timeout error on error log file:

> PHP Warning: 
>   file_get_contents(https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/self?oauth_token=XXXXXXX & a m p ; v=20161129): failed to open stream: Connection timed out

Thats weird " & is converting like  & a m p ;  " in file_get_contents

By the way , no problem on local. What is the issue? Code, my host or Block by Foursquare ?
Thank you.

Comment: `Connection timed out` is a network problem, isn't?

Comment: Yes, it is. But No problem on local app.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly probably your server cannot connect to an external resource, for example, because of `firewall restrictions`.

try to use `cURL` , it gives you more options and control than file_get_contents

OR It may be execution problem. Try `ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);` before file get contents...